# Transfer value from parent to child onclick in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Say that I have several lists in a razor component with the name ListA that have a table of rows like this:

1. List 1, FirstValue Edit
2. List 2, Antoher Value Edit
3. List 3, A third value Edit

I then have another component nested within ListA that is called ListALayout.razor.

```
<div class="WidgetHead">
@if (model == null)
{

}
else
{
    <div class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-edit cursor" @onclick="(e => OpenPopup(popup, model.PageWidgetId))"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash cursor"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        <div class="header">
            @model.Widget
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
<ListALayout Id="Id" OnWidgetChange="HandleWidgetChange" @ref="layout" />
```

I now want to edit List2 and change the value. I want to do that by using a modal that's residing insige my ListALayout component so I can change it's values and save it back to the database.

How do I transfrer the id (or model object) from my parent component to the Child component when I click the Edit button so that I know that that is the row I want to edit?

Comment: Usually you pass a `Parameter` or `CascadingParameter`, depending on the situation

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Paramter, so you can have in your Component (ListALayout.razor) defined a Parameter

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MyModelObject Model { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you can use the Parameter to set the object for this component instance:

```
 <ListALayout Model="@CurrentModelObject" />
```